# How to Make app run on different devices of iOS

Tags: ios

I am upgrading my app as per iPhone 5 method and got the way but just need help regarding the following point:

How do I use an if else condition to make the app choose the .xib file when made to run on different iPhones, especially iPhone 5?

Comment: I don't think this is the apple wants you to do it, I think they expect your one xib file to automatically adjust itself.

Answer (score 1):

You should able to utilize autoresizing masks and/or autolayout in Interface Builder to achieve this without the need for creating an entirely new `xib` file for each iPhone device form factor.

Answer (score 1):

```
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{//do iPad stuff
}

        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{//do iPhone stuff
}
```

And for images, you can look up the naming conventions on the apple dev site. I believe the iPhone 5 is used with the "-568h@2x.png" ending. The iPad is with the "~ipad.png" and "@2x ~ipad.png". The 2x is for retina displays.

Comment: And that is fairly easy to load the view from any xib file with `UINib +nibWithNibName`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the underlying device is iPhone 5 or not use the below code:

```
if ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 568)
{
// Write whatever you want here.
NSLog(@"Hello from iPhone5");
}
```